WhatsApp ESB - cannot get access_token because redirect_uri does not match
I am currently struggling with integration of WhatsApp as a Technical Provider. The main issue is with the getting access_token after user successfully process through the Facebook Login. When I take the data received from the Login flow and send the request to the https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/oauth/access_token endpoint, I get following error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 36008,
        "fbtrace_id": "AAH5Klp99JmQfQsk2MSLckg"
    }
}

I tried to search what exactly should I set and most of the responses were having correctly set the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs. I have allowed it here and also followed this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/embedded-signup/implementation
Unfortunately nothing has helped.
During development I have also tested with the hel of Embedded Signup integration Helper that you can find in the WhatsApp product in the Facebook Developer 

When you go through this Signup Flow you get all the necessary tokens and IDs to get the access_token.
You can get this token on the page. They send the following request:
curl -X POST \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/oauth/access_token' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "client_id": "123",
    "client_secret": "********************************",
    "code": "skjhfbasjfbaskjfbashbfjhas",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": "https://developers.facebook.com/es/oauth/callback/?business_id=321&nonce=ZCqFKxk0Xd1Gr7OA0unqkb22bPzMtxuZ"
  }'

What interested me was the redirect_uri in theirs request. I am not sure why, but this URI does not match the URI you invoke the login from. The page URL is https://developers.facebook.com/apps/123/whatsapp-business/es-integration/?business_id=321&session_info_version=3
I am desperate, I do not know were to what fix. Do you have any idea how could I fix this?
Thank you for any help.

It doesn't have to match the URI you invoke the login process from. You provide the URI, that the user is getting redirected back to, after they authorized your app - that's the endpoint, where you receive the code parameter. And then when you make the API request to exchange that code for a token, you need to specify the same redirect_uri value again, as you did when invoking the process.

Thanks for the answer @C3roe. I am aware of this, but from my understanding there is no way how to specify the redirect_uri to the FB login. The SDK takes it from windows.href.location. In our case there is some strange value https://staticxx.facebook.com/x/connect/xd_arbiter/?version=46#cb=xxx&domain=example.com&is_canvas=false&origin=...
I am not sure from where it takes it.

Funny thing is, here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/embedded-signup/onboarding-customers-as-a-tech-provider#step-1--exchange-the-token-code-for-a-business-token they are saying the code could be exchanged for a token without even specifying redirect_uri for that request. But that is the same endpoint as for "normal" FB apps, and in that context the parameter is definitively required. Maybe it can be left out here, because they will determine which scenario this actually is, based on the app id?

Exactly. When you try to call it without the parameter, it fails as it still compares it. So it seems as a bud in the documentation.

managed to resolve it? having exactly the same issue.

Not sure what platform you are on, but I am working on Laravel and had the same issue like mentioned here. Managed to fix by using below.
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client();

$headers = [
 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
 'Accept' => 'application/json'
];

$request = new Request(
 'GET',
 'https://graph.facebook.com/v21.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=' . $fbId . '&client_secret=' . $fbSecret . '&code=' . $code,
 $headers
);

$response = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();

$body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

if (isset($body['access_token'])) {
   return $body['access_token'];
}

Kept on getting the error message "redirect uri mismatch...." but while trying the exact same url using postman I was getting the access token successfully. So tried using PHP - Guzzle (generated code by postman) and managed to get a successful json response.
{
  "access_token": {token},
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": {time}
}

Hope that helps.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong, but this haven't helped either :-D Are you doing this within the WhatsApp integration and with help of Embedded signup Flow?
I was thinking if you need to go through App Review to be able to get this right.
How did you proceed in the matter of setting your App in Facebook Developers?

Yes we are using a "business" type meta app with "facebook login for business", "webhooks" and "whatsapp" as products, the app is on live mode with these permissions having advanced access.
whatsapp_business_messaging
whatsapp_business_management

And yes we have an embedded sign up flow exactly as what Meta mentioned under the steps. We get the waba id, phone number id and the response code to be used to generate the business token later on.

Do you also have your App reviewed and approved?

I thought I need to pass through the App Review to be able to have this working. But when I checked the process around App Review, I cannot even request the review, because the Embedded Signup Flow and onboarding is not working for me in this case. So I am absolutely blocked here.

Yes our app is reviewed and approved for the mentioned permissions.
Once you receive the authorization code did you try using postman to generate the business token?

Open your meta developer account and select your app then select Facebook Login for Business requires advanced access settings set Valid OAuth redirect URIs and remove redirect_uri from your code check attached image
